# How do I create a fixed sidebar that collapses into menu on mobile (Boostrap 4)

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navigation, nav, sidebar

I've looked all over, but I can't find the exact solution to what I want to do. I'm new to coding so it's likely a simple solution that I'm just not seeing.

I want to create a sidebar nav that is fixed on desktop and tablets, but collapses into a hamburger menu that is fixed to the top on mobile using Bootstrap 4. A lot of the examples I found used the now outdated affix property. The other examples were collapsible, but I want the sidebar to always be open on desktop and tablet. I attached photos of how I designed it on desktop and mobile for further reference.

[image: Mobile Mockup]

[image: Desktop Mockup]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post the code you are using now for your sidenav.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking about bootstrap, but since you anyway use external library for such thing, maybe this small script would be a solution for you. It does exactly what you need: https://github.com/grzegorzgit/Litomobile

If your menu is based on ul and li, this script automaticaly creates animated mobile menu and icon for the window size you want.